# Way to transform string to types

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using [pympler's muppy](https://pythonhosted.org/Pympler/muppy.html) module to retrieve information about the memory. 
What I would like to do is to be able to filter down the results by object type, like so:

```
objects = [o for o in objects if isinstance(o, Type)]
```

This works if in the code I specify the type, (e.g. Type=str) but I would also like to be able to ask users to write down the types they want to filter down. Except that when I do that, it will be stored as a string, which would give me the following:

```
isinstance(test, 'int')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

My question is, how can I get a string representing a type ('int', 'tuple', 'list', etc...) and transform it into a variable holding the type itself, so that I can use it as argument of the isinstance function.

Thank you for your help,

Comment: With a dictionary: `{'int': int, 'float': float, ...}`

Comment: If input is trusted, then you might use `eval`, e.g. `eval('tuple')`

Comment: @Arn using `eval` on user inputs is the worst idea ever... => "I would also like to be able to ask users to write down the types they want to filter down"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
builtin_types = {t.__name__: t for t in __builtins__.__dict__.values() if isinstance(t, type)}
objects = [o for o in objects if isinstance(o, builtin_types[Type])]
```

Comment: Thank you!
I noticed that for python 3 we should do:
import builtins
builtin_types = {t.__name__: t for t in builtins.__dict__.values() if isinstance(t, type)}